Help justifying this formula from my physics class
I was doing a physics class and the following analysis was done. It is about first order approximation of a function. The function is given by:
$$f(x,y) = 1 + 2e^{i\frac{3}{2}x}\cos\big{(}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\big{)} $$
This function has zeros at points $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $y = \pm \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$. From now on, let me write $\vec{x} = (x,y)$ and $\vec{a}_{\pm} = \big{(}\frac{2\pi}{3}, \pm \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\big{)}$.
The first step is to use a first order Taylor expansion. The professor wrote:
$$f(\vec{x} + \vec{a}_{\pm}) = \vec{x}\cdot (\nabla f)(\vec{a}_{\pm}) \tag{1} $$
since $f(\vec{a}_{\pm}) = 0$. Then, we can calculate the gradient:
$$(\nabla f)(\vec{a}_{\pm}) = \big{(}-\frac{3}{2}i, \pm \frac{3}{2}\big{)}$$
and we obtain:
$$f(\vec{x}+\vec{a}_{\pm}) = -\frac{3}{2}ix \pm \frac{3}{2}y \Rightarrow |f(\vec{x}+\vec{a}_{\pm})| = \frac{3}{2}|\vec{x}|$$
Finally, the main conclusion is:
$$\frac{d}{d|\vec{x}|}f(\vec{x}+\vec{a}_{\pm}) = \frac{3}{2} \tag{2}$$
I am trying to justify these steps rigorously, as I think this is possible. But I have trouble justifying relations (1) and (2). First, to justify relation (1) I believe I need to use Taylor's expansion with remainder, so I would have to add to (1) an error term of order $\vec{x}^{2}$. However, since this is a complex function of real variable, I don't know exactly how to do it. I am confused with the formulas I know, because I only heard of Taylor series for real-valued functions of real variable or complex-valued functions of complex variable.
The second step, probably most difficult to justify is (2). If I introduce an error term in (1), it will probably carry out and an error term will also appear in (2). Then I would have to take the derivative with respect to $|\vec{x}|$. Since I did not accomplish the task of justifying (1), I still can't justify (2) too.
Can someone help me?

So if I understand well, your confusion comes from the fact that you are treating a complex function as a real function, and are not sure how to Taylor expand it.
In your example, you start with a function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$. But by writting it as $f = f(x,y)$, you are actually treating it as a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, using the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ with coordinate $z = x+iy$ is the same thing as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$. (They are diffeomorphic, to speak in math terms).
Hence, for all purposes being, you can forget the complex structure, and just treat $f$ as a function on the plane.
Then, the Taylor expansion of $f$ at near $\vec{a}$ is given by:
$$f(\vec{x} + \vec{a}) = f(\vec{a}) + \vec{x}\cdot\nabla f(\vec{a}) + O(|\vec{x}|^2)$$
Where $O(|\vec{x}|^2)$ denotes terms of higher order (which we can ignore for $|\vec{x}|$ small).
And since $f(\vec{a}) = 0$, we can indeed compute, as you said:
$$f(\vec{x} + \vec{a}) \simeq \vec{x}\cdot\nabla f(\vec{a}) = (x,y)\cdot(-\frac{3}{2}i, \pm \frac{3}{2}) = -\frac{3}{2} ix \pm \frac{3}{2}y$$
So that, by taking the norm: $|f(\vec{x} + \vec{a})| \simeq \frac{3}{2}|\vec{x}|$.
If we now differentiate this last quantity with respect to the norm of $\vec{x}$, we get:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}|\vec{x}|} |f(\vec{x} + \vec{a})| \simeq \frac{3}{2}$$
Is this what you wanted to prove?
I added absolute value symbols to (2), because else I do not think that this is true. And I also replaced some of the equal signs by $\simeq$ (because we're on a math forum); since even though we're ignoring the higher-order terms, they don't have to be zero.
